# Custom dynamic validation on jquery datepicker not working until second focus

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker

I have a datepicker with a validation which pops up with a message and "!" until the user selects a date - it then shows a "O" in place of the "!" and a part of the pop up stays on the screen to show that you have completed this field.

The problem I am having though is that the validation popup does not stay on the screen until the second time you give focus to the datepicker text field.

With the validation jquery it's quite a lot of code so I don't really want to include it all here, but here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeXHE/)

Any ideas why it's not running first time but it is subsequent times?

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if `blur()` is being called before the date is picked and validated. Here's a simple solution: fade the "O" in when a valid date is picked, not on blur.

**[Working JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmgonzal/LeXHE/1/)**

Comment: actually blur is picked properly and if you inspect the element you will see that element is populated with the "O" character. If you look closely that element is always visible when the input element has some value and the notification's element innerHtml and css is modified accordingly

Answer (score 1):

the problem resides inside your `inputElementBlur(e)` function. Specifically you call

```
if (!$(e).attr("required") && ($(e).val() == "" 
         || $(e).val() == $(e).attr("defaultValue"))) {
        alert('sniarf!');
        $(blurredElement).next("div.tooltipContainer").find("span.formValid").fadeOut(100);
    }
```

i added the alert in there so you can *see* the behavior of your code. I see that while u use the `defaultValue` attribute in your validation logic you don't actually update it when the value is set.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `"defaultValue"` attribute. It's a DOM property. Fixing that made the O appear after first pickings:

http://jsfiddle.net/LeXHE/9/

Then there was some logic error with:

```
if (!$(e).attr("required") && ($(e).val() == "" || $(e).val() === $(e).prop("defaultValue"))) {
    $(blurredElement).next("div.tooltipContainer").find("span.formValid").fadeOut(100);
}
```

Which I changed to:

```
if (!$(e).attr("required") && $(e).val() == "") {
    $(blurredElement).next("div.tooltipContainer").find("span.formValid").fadeOut(100);
}
```

Comment: it's a custom attribute, which gets populated via JS.

Comment: Attribute names are case insensitive so `"defaultValue"` would be extremely poor choice for an attribute name (it's seen as `"defaultvalue"`, so at the very least `"defaultValue"` is redundant and misleading). It's also exact case sensitive match for the dom property, so I am thinking it's a mistake until the OP says otherwise.

Comment: sure, but just plucking the offending code is a poor answer imho :). besides, the OP is asking where the problem resides.

Comment: @Jaguar My answer is same as yours in that regard except I modified the condition instead of just placing alert.